# How to extract unique values of a non-factor column based on its class

Tags: r

I'm creating a `data.frame` to serve as a`codebook` for an existing `data.frame` and one of the columns of the `codebook` is the range of values within each column of the existing `data.frame`. 
I need to populate each of the unique values from a column of `class`: `character` separating them with "/"

1)i have attempted using an `if else` statement where the condition is the `class` of the column and the `function` is `unique()`

2)i have also used the `if else` statement and took the first element (using `x[1]` as the function) of the column and received the expected output

`dat` is the existing dataframe

````
function(dat){
dfr <- data.frame(
row.names = c(1:length(colnames(dat))),
ColumnNames = names(dat),
class = sapply(dat, class),
Range = sapply(dat, function(x)
  if(class(x) == "character")
           paste(unique(x), sep = " / ")
        else if(class(x) == "numeric" || class(x) == "integer")
           paste(min(x), max(x), sep = " - ")
        else
           class(x)),```

function(dat){
dfr <- data.frame(
row.names = c(1:length(colnames(dat))),
ColumnNames = names(dat),
class = sapply(dat, class),
Range = sapply(dat, function(x)
  if(class(x) == "character")
           x[1]
        else if(class(x) == "numeric" || class(x) == "integer")
           paste(min(x), max(x), sep = " - ")
        else
           class(x)),```
````

i expect the output `data.frame` to state the unique values i require under
the Range column however i get the following error message:

````
Error in data.frame(row.names = c(1:length(colnames(dat))), ColumnNames = 
names(dat),  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 68, 6```
````

However, when i used x[1] as the function, it returned the first element of the column as
 expected

Comment: I think in the first function, you need `paste(unique(x), collapse = " / ")` because if you do `paste(1:5, sep="/")`, it doesn't do anything except return character vector and changing it to `paste(1:5, collapse="/")` return a single string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP's first function

```
paste(unique(x), sep = " / ")
```

returns the same output as the input (`unique(x)`) which can be a vector of length greater than 1.  It is the only line in the function that can return a vector of length greater than 1.  The code can be changed to

```
paste(unique(x), collapse = " / ")
```

---

The difference is reproducible with

```
paste(1:3, sep=' / ')
#[1] "1" "2" "3"  # returns the same length
paste(1:3, collapse=" / ")
#[1] "1 / 2 / 3" # single string
```

Comment: thanks akrun. not sure how i didnt think to try `collapse`